# Most concise/elegant/appropriate method argument parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

Figured there'd already be an answer to this, but couldn't find one. I've been doing method option parsing a certain way, and wanted to check and make sure it's the most elegant/concise way possible.

This is what I generally do:

```
def some_method *args
  options = args.extract_options!
  options.assert_valid_keys(:key1, :key2)
  defaults = {:key1 => "one", :key2 => "two"}
  options = defaults.merge(options)

  general_arguments = args[0]
```

This, obviously, is designed to allow me to have method calls like:

```
some_method @user.id, :key1 => "good"
```

This works, but it seems a bit lengthy for Ruby, and since this is sort of my "general pattern" I wonder if it's really the way I should be doing it. Is there a better, more concise way, or a "more Rubyesque" way, of doing general options parsing?

### Assumptions

- Aggressive protection– I'm assuming methods are in a public API offered through a gem or gemmable plugin
- Defaults are desired mostly to see the patterns others use
- Potentially more than one pre-hash non-named parameter accepted

Comment: Seems like you have some implicit requirements in the question, it might be worth listing these to get a better answer, e.g. 'allow named arguments', 'provide default values' etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on who or what will be calling this method. If it's a private method, then this is definitely overkill, since all the calls to it will be encapsulated. On the other hand, if it's part of a public API within some gem you are publishing, then I think this defensive approach is appropriate.

If your use case is somewhere in the middle, you might want to take an approach that is a little less defensive, yet slightly explicit. The following is a pattern that I tend to follow when a method is public, but only has a limited number of callers. It requires a fixed number of "general arguments", and a small number of options which have defaults.

```
def my_method(id, options={})
  # Set default options
  options[:my_option] ||= "default option"

  # rest of your method goes here
end
```

Comment: Actually, this is the pattern I use for public APIs. I should have noted that.